# Regression with embedded convolution

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, convolution, linear-regression, deconvolution

I have a problem where the data I am getting is a convolution of the original data with some function and I am trying to solve the following equation for $A$ $$ Y = AX $$
where $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$, $Y$ and $X$ is the original unknown data and $A$ is unknown. Following is the data which I am receiving $$Y'(i) = h_i \circledast Y(i) \quad \forall i=1..p$$ $$X'(i) = h_i \circledast X(i) \quad \forall i=1..p$$
where $h_i$s are unknown, and $X'$ and $Y'$ are known. In short $X'$, $Y'$ are known, and $X$, $Y$, $A$ and $h_i$s are not known. I not able to find a way to solve for $A$. I would be really grateful if someone can give some pointers for it. I have asked the same question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348723

Comment: Are $ X \left( i \right) $ and $ Y \left( i \right) $ known?

Comment: It is not known. Just made a change in the question to specify it.

Comment: What are you trying to reconstruct here? As phrased, there is a degeneracy between what you can guess for $H$ and what you can guess for $A$, I believe. But you can just do alternating minimization over something that looks like $\min_{A, H^\dagger}\sum_i\|H^\dagger * Y'(i) - A*H^\dagger*X'(i)\|_2^2$, where $H^\dagger$ is an approximate "inverse" of the convolution of $H$, e.g. $H^\dagger * H \approx e_1$.

Comment: I am trying to do a regression analysis, but I don't know the underlying data. I just know that the data which is being observed is the convolution of the underlying data with some function and $A$ is a sparse matrix. So you are suggesting first to find $A$ and ${H^\dagger}$ by solving the above minimization problem and for each ${H^\dagger}$ there will exist a $H$ such that ${H^\dagger} \ast H \approx e_1$

Comment: @DushyantSahoo, It is like Blind Deconvolution with multiple samples. But I things aren't clear. Could you go through your question and specify what's know and what's not?

Comment: @Royi $X$, $Y$, $H$ and $A$ are unkown, and $X'$ and $Y'$ are known. I am trying to solve the problem for $A$.

Comment: You question is till not clear. Why do you start with $ Y = A X $ where the real question is about convolution of $ H $? First step to get assistance is be clear on the question. For instance, are $ Y \left( i \right) $ and $ X \left( i \right) $ images and $ H $ a kernel? Leave only things related to the question.

Comment: The question is about finding $A$ such that all the conditions mentioned in the question are met. $X(i) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y(i) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are some signal and $h_i$'s are vector. So, I am trying to estimate $A$ such that $Y = AX$, but I don't know the values of $Y$ and $X$. I know the values of $Y'$ and $X'$ as mentioned in the question. I would like to jointly estimate $A$ and $h_i$.

Comment: I think you should edit the question and make it more readable.